# Is there a way to keep max-height and max-weight of a div for all zoom level

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application. I want to set the width and height of a div to a fix number, no matter what zoom level. The contents inside that div can be zoomed in and out with the browser zoom level. I am able to change the background color of the div for all zoom level, but it seems the max-height and max-weight is not working for zoom.

```
@media (min-width:547px) and (max-width:683px)
{
    #rcorners1
    {
        background-color:grey;
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 150px;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Payson/ovbzwayv/)

Comment: @DrewKennedy yes. thanks. have updated post

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your media queries to use `em`'s instead of `pixel`'s.

For some further reading, check out: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/)

Comment: I don't think it works for me. can you add some sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

did you notice your typo in max-width?

```
@media (min-width:547px) and (max-width:683px) {
    #rcorners1
    {
        background-color:grey;
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 150px;
    } 
}
```

Comment: just noticed. thanks. but it's not working with correct spelling